# a React-Redux Action Update Multiple Reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux

How an Action update multiple different Reducers? How can i implement like this?

[image]

UPDATE:

this is my action in ./actions/sync.js. this action connected to an external API and call from Sync Component, periodically.

```
export function syncFetch(response) {
    return {
        type: 'SYNC_FETCH',
        response
    }
}

export function syncFetchData(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((sync) => updateAll(sync))
            .catch(() => console.log('error'));          
    };
}

const updateAll = (params) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: 'SYNC_FETCH', payload: params})
    }
}
```

and ./reducers/sync.js

```
const initialState = [];

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SYNC_FETCH':
            return action.response;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

i got not error, but data not update. what is problem in my code?

Comment: What do you mean? That's exactly how redux works. You dispatch an action (say "XYZ") and then listen to that event("XYZ") from one or more reducers. Did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

each action is being dispatched to all the reducers, the reducers may decide whether they wish to use the action to update something or not

What you want is to

```
const updateAll = params => {
    return {type: 'UPDATE_PARAMS', payload: params}
}
```

and then use it in different reducers like

```
const newReducer = (state= initialState, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
      case 'UPDATE_PARAMS': return {
         ...state,
         // do some things here
      }
      ...
      default: return state;
   }
}

const userReducer = (state= initialState, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
      case 'UPDATE_PARAMS': return {
         ...state,
         // do some things here
      }
      ...
      default: return state
   }
}
```

Comment: thax shubham, but when i use this in my action, i get ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined. what wrong?

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing this could be to fire batched actions. So you can have three different actions, one per reducer, and have a main action that takes care of all these three subsequently (or just add two actions under the first one). This can be done by using thunks ([thunk middleware](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)). To do something like, assuming they're async:

```
const updateAllNewsStuff = newsParam => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(newsAction(newsParam))
    dispatch(userAction(newsParam))
    dispatch(notifyAction(newsParam))
  }
}
```

You could probably also look at this plugin to fire batched actions:
https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions

Answer (score 5):

From `react-redux 7.1`, you can leverage the `batch` API to dispatch all the actions on a single re-render. From the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch) you can do something like:

```
import { batch } from 'react-redux'

function myThunk() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // should only result in one combined re-render, not two
    batch(() => {
       dispatch(newsAction(newsParam))
       dispatch(userAction(newsParam))
       dispatch(notifyAction(newsParam))
    })
  }
}
```